# ObservableCollection doesn't reflect changes in the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have implemented a DataGrid that way:

```
    <DataGrid 
    x:Name="MyDataGridFilter"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                x:Name="FilterTextCol01">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox 
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            IsHitTestVisible="True"
                            Text="{Binding Path=FilterTextCol01}" />
                        <CheckBox 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            x:Name="FilterAktivTextCol01"
                            IsHitTestVisible="True"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=FilterAktivTextCol01}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The binding in the Code goes this way:

```
FilterItemsList = new ObservableCollection<DataGridFilterEntity>();
MyDataGridFilter.DataContext = FilterItemsList;
```

(it is shorted)
FilterItemsList is implemented as an INotifyPropertyChanged clas:

```
public class DataGridFilterEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

With the member FilterTextCol01 (of course):

```
public string FilterTextCol01
    {
        get { return _FilterTextCol01; }
        set
        {
            _FilterTextCol01 = value;
            Changed("FilterTextCol01");
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine. When I change the FilterItemsList the DataGrid refelcts these changes.
But when I make some changes in the UI (in the DataGrid) it isn't reflected by the ObservableCollection (FilterItemsList).

I searched and tried some hours but did not find any solution.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: @AngelWPF Sorry, up until yesterday I didn't know the usage of acceptance and so forth. I'm going to make up for it!

Comment: @AngelWPF Please let me know if anything else is not correct with my profile! I haven't yet answered question because my knowledge is quite poor at the moment. But that will change ...

Comment: nopes... its fine. But let me know what changes you are doing in the GUI?

Comment: @AngelWPF I took only the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged that is sufficient to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need TwoWay binding.

For example,

```
 <TextBox 
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True"
                        Text="{Binding Path=FilterTextCol01, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
   <CheckBox 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        x:Name="FilterAktivTextCol01"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=FilterAktivTextCol01, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: I dont think this needs explicitly set `TwoWay` binding really. `CheckBox` and `TextBox`'s `IsChecked` and `Text` properties are two way bound by default. Also `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` could make the GUI slower.

Comment: @Pongsthon.keng Thank you! UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is my solution. I didn't know that.

Comment: So that means you wanted the data to update at the moment your type text in the textbox? Not when you focus off the textbox?

Comment: @AngelWPF Yes, i agree with you commend for TwoWay Binding for some of dependency properties. so, I think that to add that for readability, just would like to make sure who read code understand that.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of changes are you doing to the GUI? Are you updating the `Text` of the `TextBox` and checking the `CheckBox`?

If so the same example works in my case. I receive the updated text and checked boolean back in my model when I focus off the textbox or checkbox.